# What could be a good use case for Immutable Singleton classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, immutability

Without going into a discussion whether Singleton is an anti-pattern in itself, I'm looking for a good use case for Immutable Singleton.

The only instance of such class will have a constant value once initialized, since we can neither change its visible state nor create an another copy.

What is a real-life use of such constructs?

**P.S.**

Other than `Enum` please.

Comment: Any place you use a constant that cannot practically be initialized by the compiler.

Comment: @Hot Licks - So just a replacement of `static public final`?

Comment: Utility classes may also be immutable singletons, although that's just an extension of what Hot Locks said.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Utility classes do not really have state.

Comment: How is `static public final` not a singleton?

Comment: @HotLicks - if you have a public constructor. How *is* it a singleton?

Comment: Enums can be thought of as a good usecase for immutable singletons. In fact I think an immutable singleton is the only safe singleton to use anyway .)

Comment: @HotLicks - Sorry, I did not make myself clear. AFAIK, singleton's role is to preserve an application state (similarly to `static` field's in a class). So immutable singleton will play application-wide constant role similar to `static final` field inside a class.

Comment: A public static final field is essentially indistinguishable from a singleton.

Comment: @PM77-1 Utility classes can *absolutely* have state, e.g., caches, connection managers, configurable elements, etc. are all stateful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be an example of an immutable singleton:

```
public class DatabaseAccess
{
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;

    private final String dbUrl;
    private final String dbDriver;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    private DatabaseAccess()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try { properties.load(new FileInputStream("db.properties")); }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // exception handling
        }

        dbUrl = properties.getProperty("dbmanager.url");
        dbDriver = properties.getProperty("dbmanager.driver");
        username = properties.getProperty("user.login");
        password = properties.getProperty("user.password");
    }

    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DatabaseAccess();

        return instance;
    }

    public Connection getNewConnection() { ... }

    // other methods ...

}
```

You want to read the properties once and only once for each JVM restart.

Comment: BlackBrain nails it; the database connection pool is typically one good use of a Singleton.  I'd rephrase as "you want to read the properties once and only once for each JVM restart".

Comment: @DeanJ You're right ;)